# Access SQL With PIVOT

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Access and attempting to duplicate some syntax I found on MSDN. Unfortunately it seems Access is having a problem with a FROM statement in my Syntax. I'm not sure why.

```
SELECT YEAR, HC
FROM
(
SELECT [Retention & Graduation].Year, [Retention & Graduation].Status, [Retention & Graduation].Hc
FROM [Retention & Graduation]
) AS X

PIVOT
(
SUM([HC]) FOR [STATUS] IN ([GONE], [HERE], [GRAD])
) AS Xx
```

Comment: Can you share the schema, sample input/output data? For Access, the construct is [`TRANSFORM`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/transform-statement-HP001032277.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax to pivot in MS Access is different from sql server. You have to use the [`TRANSFORM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208956%28v=office.12%29.aspx) function to pivot data.

The syntax will be similar to this:

```
TRANSFORM SUM([Retention & Graduation].Hc)
SELECT [Retention & Graduation].Year, 
  [Retention & Graduation].Status, 
  [Retention & Graduation].Hc
FROM [Retention & Graduation]
GROUP BY [Retention & Graduation].Year
PIVOT [Retention & Graduation].[STATUS]
```

Comment: Outstanding. It's so simple, isn't it?

Comment: I removed the  [Retention & Graduation].Status, 
  [Retention & Graduation].Hc from the SELECT clause to suit my needs. Thanks!!!