# ACCESS: Rearranging query results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like this one:

[image: table 1]

And would like to reorder it like this:

[image: tabe 2]

Is this possible with SQL code?

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137992/access-sql-with-pivot) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208956(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

HERE IT IS

```
SELECT PRODUCT , [2015] SALES2015,[2016] SALES2016
FROM YOUR_TABLE  X
PIVOT
( SUM(sales) 
FOR 
[year] IN ([2015], [2016])
)PV
```

Comment: I think you need [`TRANSFORM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208956(v=office.12).aspx) for Access.