# How to pivot between current day and previous days

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

I'm using Access SQL

I have data that looks like this:-

| dealdate | value |
| --- | --- |
| 17-Apr-22 | 267 |
| 18-Apr-22 | 274 |

I'm trying to make the data look like this (there will only ever be 2 dates)
So, assuming that today is 18th April:-

| CurrentDay | PreviousDay | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 274 | 267 | 7 |

How can I do this with Access SQL?

Comment: I don't know how exactly to do it, but a PIVOT is what you need. I believe in Access it is used as TRANSFORM. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137992/access-sql-with-pivot

Comment: is there an id number or something -- or is it current day and prior day the only rows?

Answer (score 0):

Pivot would be a big mistake -- you can just use a where and a join --- looks something like this:

```
SELECT today.value as CurrentDay,
       yesterday.value as PreviousDay,
       today.value - yesterday.value as Difference
FROM sometableyoudidnotname AS today
WHERE today.dealdate = DATE()
LEFT JOIN sometableyoudidnotname as yesterday
            ON today.id = yesterday.id and yesterday.dealdate = DATEADD("d", -1 ,DATE())
```

Comment: yesterday and today are not tables however - that is the problem.  there is just a table that holds rows whereby one column holds the dates.

Comment: @tintedsepia in this query the names yesterday and today are aliases for the queries -- this is using the name "sometableyoudidnotname" as a place holder for your table name -- replace that with your actual table name and this query will work.

Answer (score 0):

Using 3 calculated variables and the Query Designer:

[image]

```
PreviousDay: Nz(DLookUp("dealvalue","Table1","dealdate = #" & DateAdd("d",-1,CDate([dealdate])) & "#"),0)
```

```
'Full SQL


SELECT Table1.dealvalue AS CurrentDay, Nz(DLookUp("dealvalue","Table1","dealdate = #" & DateAdd("d",-1,CDate([dealdate])) & "#"),0) AS PreviousDay, [dealvalue]-[PreviousDay] AS Difference
FROM Table1;
```

giving:

---

### |     CurrentDay     |    PreviousDay     |     Difference     |

### |                267 | 0                  |                267 |

### |                274 | 267                |                  7 |

Notes:

1. in VBA Dates in strings are delimited by #
2. Previous day assumed to be 0 on first day
3. you can replace the dlookup function with subquerys
   for more portability, but it takes me an hour to write my subquerys so I used dlookup.
4. cdate is used for robustness it may not be needed depending on the format and type of dealdate